# Custom to light yahrzeit candle on Erev Shabbos before the yahrzeit

Tags: minhag, shabbat, time, lighting, yahrtzeit

Has anyone heard of a custom to light a yahrzeit candle not on the eve of the actual yahrzeit, but on the eve of the preceding Shabbos? I know that there are other customs for the preceding Shabbos, such as saying kaddish, davening for the amud, possibly saying Kel Malei Rachamim, etc.--but is burning the memorial candle over that Shabbos also a tradition by anyone? (By whom?)

Motive: I am trying to find out if it could be my family's actual custom to do so, or if a relative instructed me to do this based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: *Kel Maleh Rachamim* is often said on the Shabbat before simply b/c that may be the closest Torah-reading day to the yahrtzeit, and this prayer must be said when the Torah is read. As for Kaddish - are you sure it's not simply b/c the person saying it can't come to shul on a weekday? Davening for the amud - I have to check if that's even common minhag. Usually, on Shabbat, someone who has yahrtzeit is not allowed to daven for the amud.

Comment: I looked at some sources about yahrzeits and could not find such a custom (though that's not a definitive proof that it doesn't exist; it may just mean it's not popular or well-known). Maybe contact that relative and try to get more clarity?

Comment: @Jay I might. It sounds like he misunderstood. Although I do feel like I see a lot of yahrzeit candles lit along with Shabbos candles...

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75/1516